# Error in connecting SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a LAN network consisting of 2 laptops where my friend's laptop is acting as a server and my laptop is acting as a client...I could detect my friend's instance i.e PC/SQLEXPRESS an d so can he....

I have created a login name and password in his laptop(i.e SQL server) and even the TCP/IP and named pipes is selected on both Laptops and the Firewall Disabled...However it's not accepting the given username and login in the SQL SERVER AUTHENTICATION...and is giving error "Connection Failed : Login 'Sujit' cannot be connected to a trusted SQL SERVER".....

please help....

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the right site for this question I suspect that it'll get migrated somewhere.

On the SQL Server you are connecting to does it show the login failure in the SQL server logs? If so I think there should be an error subcode that you can google to find out the exact problem.

Comment: @Martin.....it's a pop up window....

Answer (score 0):

1. In Object Explorer: Right click Your
   Server and open Properties
2. Select Security in the left pane of
   the properties window
3. On the right side you will see
   Server Authentication
4. Select  "SQL Server and Windows
   Authentication Mode"
5. Close the properties windows by
   clicking OK
6. Restart your Server by right
   clicking your Server and choosing
   restart

Try login now

**Edit:**

[Server Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t900cyed%28VS.71%29.aspx)

[SQl Serve Management studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio)

Comment: @Muhammad Kashif...i could'nt find Object Explorer....my server is stored in Server Explorer....Right Clicked....But the 'Properties' option is inactive...

Comment: @sujitanand Don't you have SQL Server Management Studio? Server Explorer is in Visual Studio and you can not manage your server from Server Explorer. See Two links in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the SQL Server Surface Area Configuration, since this is Express, remote connections are disabled by default.
2. Once you are in The SA Config window, click on Surface Area Config for Services and Connections.
3. Click on Remote Connections under Database Engine
4. Select Local and Remote Connections, and choose your type. (TCP, named pipes, or both)